# How to create a dictionary variable that may contains only specific class and children of this class

Tags: typescript

I need build a tree where each node of tree may be an instance of base node or child of base node.

I have a class `BaseNode` that has a property `nodes` this property should contains instances of BaseNode or children of BaseNode.
I wrote a simple code bellow but compiler throw an error `Type 'BaseNode' is not assignable to type 'T'.` in the method `getNodeById`

```
interface NodeDictionary <T extends BaseNode> { 
  [index: string]: T;
};

class BaseNode {
  private nodes: NodeDictionary<BaseNode> = {};

  constructor(private id: string, private name: string) {
  }

  getId() { 
    return this.id;
  }

  append<T extends BaseNode>(node: T) { 
    this.nodes[node.getId()] = node;
  }

  getNodeById<T extends BaseNode>(id: string): T { 
    return this.nodes[id];
  }
}

class ExtendBaseNode extends BaseNode {
  someMethod() { 
  }
 }

let a = new BaseNode('A', 'My name is A');
let b = new ExtendBaseNode('B', 'My name is B');
a.append<ExtendBaseNode>(b);
```

How to explain to compiler that the prop `nodes` may has contains instances of BaseNode or children of BaseNode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your signature for that specific method conflicts with what you return. Since `nodes` basically strictly contains `BaseNode` objects it is not possible to automatically typecast into a superclass such as `ExtendBaseNode`. Although `T` can be a `BaseNode` it just can be `ExtendBaseNode` as well.

I suggest the following change

```
getNodeById<T extends BaseNode>(id: string): T { 
    return this.nodes[id] as T;
}
```

which will typecast the return value to the `T` type as you'd expect in the first place.

Under the assumption the the types are correct this code works as expected:

```
let a = new BaseNode('A', 'My name is A');
let b = new ExtendBaseNode('B', 'My name is B');
a.append(b);
console.log(a.getNodeById<ExtendBaseNode>('B'));
```